# DevExtreme dxGrid's tooltip not behaving consistent in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, devextreme

I've got a [dxGrid](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/) which renders like this in [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/):

[image: dxGrid with tooltip on Chrome]

The same grid when seen in [Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/microsoft-edge) doesn't shows tooltips:

[image: dxGrid without tooltip on Edge]

Is this a bug? If yes, is there a way I can forcefully show a tooltip on Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bug. It works fine. If you're really interested in forcefully showing a kind of tooltip, use [`cellTemplate`](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/?version=16_1#cellTemplate)

```
cellTemplate: function(container, options) {
            container.attr("title", "Your tooltip data goes here");
          }
```

Comment: I'm able to see the bug. Please see screenshots in my question

Comment: I don't think so. I've seen it working fine. Please try `cellTemplate`.

Comment: What will I do with it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see it again. It will append a title attribute, which will show the tooltip.